# Profile Page Layout Issue - Long Tag Name

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I just saw that a very small issue in [profile page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/54133/cl%C3%A9ment) of one user.

[image]

Comment: The page points to another site pro webmasters. better you could ask it there.

Comment: yes. that's why I didn't take any other action like CV. but try to take it to most appropriate site

Comment: But all sites use same design???